# Scrollable div in table cell

Tags: css, html, tablelayout

I'm trying to create a table layout with a header along the top, some content in the left and a scrollable section on the right. What I've done works in Safari and Chrome, but for some reason it doesn't work in Firefox, the scrollable div in the cell on the right doesn't scroll but instead pushes the table bigger...

I've heard that these days you shouldn't use tables but instead use all divs, but how would you make a 2-column layout with a header area like this without a table?

http://jsfiddle.net/zS8vy/3/

Here's some of my CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

table tr td.rightScroll {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}

table tr td.rightScroll div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**EDIT:** OK I found the problem, I hadn't set `height: 100%` on the `tr` and `tbody` elements. Now it all scrolls properly, but the content is off by the size of the header, for example if you scroll the right content to the bottom you can see it's getting cut off...

Comment: You fiddle works for me in ie. Which verson of IE are you using?

Comment: Sorry it does seem to work in IE, it's Firefox with the problem...

Comment: You can also go for div layout instead of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a fiddle please check this its a little different but its working in all browser

http://jsfiddle.net/zS8vy/7/

```
 body, td, div, p, a {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td.header {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #BBB;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

table tr td.content {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #AAA;
    position:relative;
}

table tr td.rightScroll {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;

    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #999;
   display:table-cell;


}

table tr td.rightScroll div {
 width:200px;
    height:calc(100% - 28px);
position:absolute;
    top:28px;

    right:0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: It works but now the content is going over the header at the top... How do you move it down without cutting off at the bottom?

Comment: let me try to create a fiddle

Comment: Interesting creative solution, but it is absolutely (and relatively) insane that we have to go to such an extent just to get scrollable content in a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

For table `tr td.rightScroll div` First change overflow-y:scroll; to overflow-y:auto;

```
table tr td.rightScroll div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%; //height should be fixed say 80% / 200px to enable content scrolling
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: Changing `overflow-y` to `auto` just removed the scroll bar, the content is still pushing the table bigger...

Comment: You are using height: 100%; for all sections that is making everything expand vertically with tables, are you looking for fixed ? fluid layout, please?

Comment: A fixed layout, the only part that should scroll is the list of items on the right...

Comment: This answer is on the right path, but the height needs to be defined in pixels, not percentage... http://jsfiddle.net/zS8vy/4/

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the height of it is beforehand, it needs to be 100% of the screen minus the size of the header cell...

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr td.rightScroll {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto; //change height to Auto
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 5px;
}

table tr td.rightScroll {
    vertical-align: top;  //Align scrollable div to top inside <td>
}

table tr td.rightScroll div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; //Give fixed height to enable scroll to <DIV>
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is I don't know what size to give to the div, it should be 100% of the screen minus the size of the header...

Comment: @jjv360 Please read this article might be of help for you to understand - [link](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-css-cascading-style-sheets-web-design-isbn-978-0-7645-7642-3/50444-scrollable-content-fluid-layout-problem.html)