# Scrollable div in table-cell doesn't work

Tags: css, firefox, scrollable, css-tables

I've got the following HTML code:

```
<header>
    header
</header>
<nav>
    nav
</nav>
<div class="content">
    <div class="box">
        content<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

`body` is displayed as `table`

`header`, `nav` and `.content` as table-cells.

I would like to make `div.content` scrollable. Since you can't fix that with a table-cell, I added an extra `div` to it, and add `overflow: auto` to it.

The full CSS looks like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
header, nav, .content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
header {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}
nav {
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
.content {
    background: lightgreen;
}
.box {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Also check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5ab2/1/).

This code seems to work in IE9 and Opera12, but not in Firefox26.

Anyone got an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: give content a height and it will work

Comment: @Huangism, nope, [it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/c5ab2/2/).

Comment: 100% won't work, needs to be a defined number. This might also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920061/scrollable-div-in-table-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with a little piece of jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $(".box").height( $(window).height()+"px" );
}).resize();
</script>
```

It gives `.box` the window height on page load en resize.